# SQL IF value is found do ELSE do something else

Tags: mysql

**Question**

How can I get a simple table `userType = employee` or `userType = employer` if userID is found within the table employer.

**Tried to do**

With the following code I can get a return that sais this user is an employer when he is one, when he's not I get nothing.

`SELECT (CASE WHEN (userID IS NOT NULL) THEN 'employer' ELSE 'employee' END) AS 'userType' FROM tblEmployer WHERE userID = 401`

Also tried with and if statement

```
IF EXSISTS (SELECT userID FROM tblEmployer WHERE userID = 401) 
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblEmployer WHERE userID = 401) > 0) ELSE ...
```

But this gives `Assignment type not recognized. (near "IF" at position 0)`

Comment: Try IFNULL(SQL, VAL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return exactly one row, then use aggregation or a subquery in the `select` clause:

```
select (case when exists (select 1
                          from tblEmployer e
                          where e.userId = 401
                         )
             then 'employer' else 'employee'
        end) as userType
```

Alternatively:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 'employer' else 'employee' end) as userType
from tblEmployer e
where e.userId = 401;
```